# How to discover the overrided methods in Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, overriding

Hey guys.
How do I know the methods that a child class overrided in my super class?
I have this:

```
class Test
  def self.inherited(child)
    # child.overrided_methods???
  end

  def self.foo
  end

  def self.bar
  end
end

def Child < Test
  def self.bar
    puts "bar"
  end
end
```

The method self.inherited is called when a subclass of Test is loaded. So I get the reference to this subclass in child, but I don't know how to get the methods that were overrided by this subclass.

Any ideas?

--

Arsen suggested the use of self.method_added(name) instead of self.inherited(child), but this method catches only instance methods and I want to catch class methods. Does anyone know another methods that does the same thing but with class methods?
In the last case I'll consider using a singleton and convert all this class methods to instance methods then the problem is solved.

Comment: To clarify: are you trying to call `Child`'s methods from `Test`?

Comment: Yes. I want to know what methods Child overrided. They are all class methods and child variable is a reference to the class Child.

Comment: How about the simplest approach: "`Child.methods(false) & Test.methods(false)`"? The problem is: when do you want to call it? 'Inherited' is called too early.

Comment: Ok, I have found the solution. My answer is undeleted and updated. I hope I didn't mess anything this time ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instance methods there is an `Object::method_added(name)` method you can override, similar to 'inherited' you have used:

```
class test
  def self.method_added(name)
    puts "method_added(#{name.inspect})"
    super
  end
end

irb(main):002:0> class Child < Test; def foo; end; end
method_added(:foo)
=> nil
```

You can then compare a received name to a list of your methods:

```
Test.instance_methods.include?(name.to_s)
```

With class methods this approach does not work (even if you do things like `class << self` magic), but a helpful fellow knew the answer: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/120416 :

```
class Test
  def self.singleton_method_added(name)
    puts "Class method added #{name.inspect}"
  end
end
```

This is only the first part of the problem, because you need to know which class defined the method (it will be self) and whether the method is a new one, or overridden one. Experiment with this code:

```
class Test
  def self.singleton_method_added(name)
    if self == Test
      puts "My own class method added: #{self.name}.#{name.inspect}"
    elsif Test.methods(false).include?(name.to_s)
      puts "Class method overriden: #{self.name}.#{name.inspect}"
    elsif Test.methods(true).include?(name.to_s)
      puts "My parent's class method overriden: #{self.name}.#{name.inspect}"
    else
      puts "New class method added: #{self.name}.#{name.inspect}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot Arsen7! Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation (15) here to vote you up...  =/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a first step to the solution:

By calling `child.instance_method(:bar)` (if child refers to the class) or `child.method(:bar)` (if it refers to an instance of Child) you can get an `UnboundMethod` or `Method` object representing your method:

```
a = Test.instance_method(:foo)
b = Child.instance_method(:foo)
```

Unfortunately, `a == b` evaluates to false, although both refer to the same method.

Comment: My mistake. I forgot to put the 'self.' before all methods definitions. They are all class methods. So, I tried what you said (using child.method(:bar) and child.method(:foo)) and both executed without UnboundMethod. I guess it goes without mistake to foo method because he uses the super class method.

Answer (score 0):

```
def overridden_methods
  klass = self.class
  klass.instance_methods.select {|m| klass.instance_method(m).owner == klass}
end
```

Change according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks Tass, but as I said before, I was trying to catch the class method not instance methods. Arsen found the way to solve the problem up here.